# I want to use my GPU for trainig, but everytime my kernel freezes and restart itself in .fit step

Tags: python, tensorflow

I hope you can help me get over this issue.
my python version is 3.7, Tensorflow & Keras are 2.8.0, pandas is 1.3.4 and NumPy is 1.21.6
also, my Cuda & CuDnn versions are the latest which are 11.6.2 & 8.4.0, respectively.
whenever I want to train my network, in the fit step, my kernel just freezes and restarts itself, but when I switch to CPU mode, everything works just fine. I also provide you with my code in case you are curious about how I implement them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import pathlib
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU, ReLU
import pandas as pd
```

---

```
model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(8, 3, 3, padding='same', activation=activation),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 3, padding='same', activation=activation),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 3, padding='same', activation=activation),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
             loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
             metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=150,
    verbose=1,
)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share the error log as well; 
What is kernel exactly referring to? is it python kernel? or it is OS related?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SadraNaddaf There is no reference, just it freezes in epoch 1/150, and after a while, it pops up that kernel just restarted

Comment: @hosseinshahverdi, This error might have been caused due to the incompatibilities between the versions of CUDA and cuDNN. Please check the tested build configurations for [Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu), [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and [macOs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu_2) and install the compatible versions of CUDA and cuDNN. Please let us know if the issue resolves. Thank you.

Comment: @TFer Hello dear TFer. yeah, i checked the Tensorflow-Gpu website and downloaded the compatible version with python 3.8. but so far there is no success of implementing my code with GPU.